# Prevent destruction of linebreaks in gist.github.com?

Tags: github, gist

EDIT: Youtube video demonstrating the issue:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0D0rNfUhiKQ

EDIT: `Pasting` is critical here. When I paste 10 lines copied from a text editor, `gist.github.com` spews it into 1 line.

I'm pasting this into gist.github.com

```
return (
  <div className="App">
    <h1>Quantum Pilot</h1>
      <div className="content">
        <div className="box"><About/></div>
        <div className="box">HnnYoutube</div>
        <div className="box">{buy}</div>
        <div className="box">{mykeys}</div>
      </div>
      <MetamaskPrompt enabled={this.state.metamask}/>
  </div>
);
```

10 lines but - gist.github.com turns into 1 line, poorly spaced. If I click "soft wrap", it takes up 2 lines.

Why are my newlines being destroyed?

Comment: Pasting just work, see my answer.

Comment: What OS are you using and what program are you copying from?

Comment: Try switching to UNIX line terminators in Sublime Text, maybe the editor doesn't work properly with \r newlines and expects \n or \r\n only.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you are using the backtick in your gist, in order to preserve the format:

`````
````
your code
your code
...
your code
````
`````

That way, you will preserve those lines as they are formatted initially.

Note: your gist should be named with an `.md` extension (markdown).

See mine: [`testwrap.md`](https://gist.github.com/VonC/187816c43ddbb06d3e2d5a2723b2552f#file-testwrap-md):

[image: test wrap]

Comment: Do you have an example?

Comment: https://gist.github.com/quantumproducer/644d4927250f49f60f73c6f20f2eaad9

Comment: I see only 3 backticks in there. You should put 4.

Comment: @quantumpotato Can you rename it in gistfile1.md?

Comment: @quantumpotato I have edited my answer with an example.

Comment: The usual way to format large blocks of code in markdown is to use 4-space indentation. Backticks (`like this`) are generally for shorter in-line code samples. See my example here: https://gist.github.com/Keith-S-Thompson/a28b871a191e3459b81139d75e10a628

Comment: @KeithThompson In this instance, (4) backticks are appropriate. No space needed.

Comment: Why are backticks more appropriate than spaces?

Comment: @VonC  Keith when I paste my code, it comes in as 1 line. Even though in my editor it is 10 lines. Is there a way to fix this happening when I paste?

Comment: @quantumpotato: My guess is that the problem occurs when you copy it. If you copy from your editor window, it will copy the character sequence your editor used to display the text, which might not match the actual contents. What editor are you using? Can you find another way to copy the text, say something like `cat filename` and then copy from the terminal window?

Comment: @KeithThompson because in this instance, you can just paste (with LF or CRLF) between your backticks, and move on. No EOL issue, no formatting to think of. Just paste.

Comment: I added a Youtube video demonstrating the problem.

Comment: Please demonstrate a video yourself as I tried your solution and couldn't replicate.